# Is this the best pattern for creating objects that have been JSON serialized?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm working on a project where I have a nice set of objects that I would like to serialize and send down the wire when a user calls my REST api. The problem is that simply `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` will not support methods, private data and properties defined with `Object.defineProperty/defineProperties`; Only the publicly visible fields are [de]serialized.

I haven't come across many examples of a consumer of a javascript API deserializing the response payload to a POJO with members, properties, etc. The simple pattern I've come up with isn't very interesting and I'm wondering if there are more common or superior patterns for essentially accomplishing the same thing?

Consider this example:

```
var myType = function(name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age  = age;
}
//  Add some properties
Object.defineProperties(myType.prototype, {
    'name': { get: function() {return this._name;} },
    'age':  { get: function() {return this._age;} }
});
//  Add a method
myType.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this._name + ' is ' + this._age;
}
//  Add a 'static' deserialize method
myType.fromJSON = function(serializedMe) {
    var tmp = JSON.parse(serializedMe);
    return new myType(tmp._name, tmp._age);
}

var i = new myType('Steve', 38);
console.log('I am ' + i.name + ' and my age is ' + i.age);

//  Simulate serialization
var payloadToSend = JSON.stringify(i);

//  Send to client...

//  Client wants to work with full-fledged myType instance...
var clientInstanceOfMyType = myType.fromJSON( payloadToSend );
console.log(clientInstanceOfMyType.toString());
```

Is that the best I can do? I suppose it comes down to the best creation pattern for creating an object with methods and properties from JSON.

Comment: That's how I'd do it. Take serialize to a simple JSON object with the data members you need, send it across, then reconstruct the full object on the other side.

Comment: Echoing @James Tanner, this is similar to my solution for this problem, but I formalize it a bit more. The syntax gets cleaner with ES6 classes of Typescript classes/interfaces.